# When is the IOC container ready?

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control

When is the IOC container in the life cycle of an ASP.NET application?

When can I start requesting objects from the container?

Comment: What IOC container? This is usually something you setup in e.g. Application_Start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which container you are talking about (Windsor, StructureMap, Ninject, etc) they are generally available immediately after creation.

You typically create the container in the Application_Start event.